# Extend WP_List_Table class - Edit wp_usermeta - WPPB.me Boilerplate - Action error

Tags: plugin-development, customization, wp-list-table

I’m developing a WordPress plugin where the goal/ action is to manipulate data in the wp_usermeta table, by extending the WP_List_Table class, and using it in the WPPB.me boilerplate. I’ve been able to get my table to work outside of the boilerplate, for example, if I just put my action functions in the same “wp-list-table-example-page.php”, after the code for the extended class itself. But, I want to use the boilerplate where the _REQUEST’s would be sent to separate pages in the ./partials folder (assuming that’s the correct way). I have both row and bulk actions included by extending the WP_List_Table class. I’m stuck on getting the actions to function properly; to load the custom ./partials pages I created in the boilerplate to perform the requested actions when either a row  is clicked, or the bulk action drop down is used with checkboxes in a table column.

Here’s what I’m working with in the file:
(edit: fixed file path for clarity)
http URL is:
www/zapper/wp-admin/admin.php?page=zapper-table

```
<?php // ./wp-content/plugins/zapper/includes/class-zapper-list-table.php :



if(!defined('PLUGIN_TEXT_DOMAIN')){
    define('PLUGIN_TEXT_DOMAIN', 'zapper');
}

if(!class_exists('WP_List_Table')){
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

class Zapper_List_Table extends WP_List_Table
{

   /* other extended WP_List_Table stuff withheld  */ 
    function get_bulk_actions()
    {
        $actions = array(
            'view_all'    => __('View Multi', 'PLUGIN_TEXT_DOMAIN'),
            'edit_all' => __('Edit Multi', 'PLUGIN_TEXT_DOMAIN')
        );
        return $actions;
    }

    public function handle_table_actions() {
        
        // check for row actions
        $the_table_action = $this->current_action();
        
        if ( 'view_meta' === $the_table_action ) {
            $nonce = wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] );
            // verify the nonce.
            if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'view_meta_nonce' ) ) {
                $this->invalid_nonce_redirect();
            }
            else {                    
                $this->page_view_meta( absint( $_REQUEST['user_id']) );
                $this->graceful_exit();
            }
        }
        
        if ( 'add_meta' === $the_table_action ) {
            $nonce = wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] );
            // verify the nonce.
            if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'add_meta_nonce' ) ) {
                $this->invalid_nonce_redirect();
            }
            else {                    
                $this->page_add_meta( absint( $_REQUEST['user_id']) );
                $this->graceful_exit();
            }
        }
        
        // check for bulk actions
        if ( ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && $_REQUEST['action'] === 'bulk-edit' ) || ( isset( $_REQUEST['action2'] ) && $_REQUEST['action2'] === 'bulk-edit' ) ) {
            
            $nonce = wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] );
            // verify the nonce.
            
            if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'bulk-users' ) ) {
                $this->invalid_nonce_redirect();
            }
            else {
                $this->page_bulk_edit( $_REQUEST['users']);
                $this->graceful_exit();
            }
        }
        
    }


    public function page_view_meta( $user_id ) {
        
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );        
        include_once( 'admin/partials/zapper-view-meta.php' );
    }
    
    public function page_edit_meta( $user_id ) {
        
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );        
        include_once( 'admin/partials/zapper-edit-meta.php' );
    }
    

    public function page_bulk_edit( $bulk_user_ids ) {
                
        include_once( 'admin/partials/zapper-bulk-edit.php' );
    }      
}
?>
```

The result when clicking a row action is basically nothing, it just refreshes the page. Using the dropdown for a bulk action– while no error is thrown by WP– it directs to a blank page, with the following in the URL parameters:

```
?_wpnonce=183ef79f5e
&_wp_http_referer=/zapper/wp-admin/admin.php
?page=zapper-table
&action=edit_all
&paged=1
&element[]=9
&element[]=4
&element[]=11
&action2=edit_all
```

In my previous, successful tests, I don’t have the &_wp_http_referer or &paged=1 and I don’t understand why it’s there in this trial. And that is only on a bulk action request. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, as I've got two "?" in the URL params.

What have I've done wrong?
Thank you!

**EDIT:**
I changed the include_once './path' to `include_once( WP_PLUGIN_DIR .'/... ')`, but i'm getting the same results:

```
    public function page_edit_meta( $user_id ) {
        
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );        
        if(file_exists(WP_PLUGIN_DIR .'/zapper/partials/zapper-edit-meta.php')){
        return "<h1>FILE EXISTS!</h1>";
         die();
        }
        else {
                return "<h1>FILE NOT EXISTS!</h1>";
                die();
        }
        include_once( WP_PLUGIN_DIR .'/zapper/partials/zapper-edit-meta.php' );

    }
```

Changing that path, and adding die(); did not change the behavior at all. I expected it at least to exit. Now I'm really confused. It has to be going into the function if it's redirecting the page?..

**EDIT2:**
The code in the page it's supposed to go to is as follows (but I don't see how that would be relevant here?).

```
<?php

/**
 * @file '/zapper/partials/zapper-edit-meta.php
 */

    if( current_user_can('edit_users' ) ) { ?>
        <h2> <?php echo __('Process bulk operations for the selected users: <br>', $this->plugin_text_domain ); ?> </h2>
        <h4>
            <ul>
            <?php
                foreach( $bulk_user_ids as $user_id ) {
                    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
                    echo '<li>' . $user->display_name . ' (' . $user->user_login . ')' . '</li>';
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </h4>
        <div class="card">
            <h4> HTML Form to Edit Meta goes here </h4>
        </div>
        <br>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'page' => wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['page'] ) ) , admin_url( 'admin.php' ) ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Back', $this->plugin_text_domain ) ?></a>
<?php
    }
    else {  
?>
        <p> <?php echo __( 'Not authorized', $this->plugin_text_domain ) ?> </p>
<?php   
    }
```

Comment: when i click the fucntion page_edit_meta( $user_id ) in the example, above, the resulting URL is `./admin.php?page=zapper-table&action=view_meta&user_id=9` 
(the actual ID numbers being irrelevant, but apparently i clicked on whoever is ID[9])

Comment: i've tried this with both `admin_url( 'admin.php' )` and `admin_url( 'users.php' )`
a WP_List_Table tutorial I'd used was going off of users.php. In my case, I haven't noticed any difference for which base file .php was used. I don't understand quite why, but i'm assuming because of the value in the url where "?page= ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

I received [guidance at WordPress.org which helped me](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/extending-wp_list_table-problem-with-_wp_http_referer-wppb-me-boilerplate/) solve this problem. The solution-- if i recall-- circumvented any need to further pursue what i was trying to do above (basically).

I don't recall precisely what was causing my issue as posted here, in the o/p, but I can check if anyone ever encounters issues w/ that, or WP_List_Table class in general. I think it was a Namespace issue which my code inherited (purposefully) from a tutorial i'd been following on the topic.

The "working" product is here if anyone would like to look at the code, please be my guest. I believe it was quite reworked from my approach in the o/p:

https://github.com/ajaxStardust/wp_zapper

feedback welcome!
Cheers!